# javascript third XMLHttpRequest refused.. yet first two allowed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, xmlhttprequest

I am using Jquery to make a request to an API and return the data serialized. But after doing the exact same call slightly different a third time... I get refused with the following error.

`No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:1337' is therefore not allowed access.`

Then how come the first two times I access the API through the exact same method are allowed? The call is exactly the same.. the url is the same except for a different endpoint.. everything is the same except that I'm requesting a different endpoint on the same domain. And obviously how the data is being handled but I don't ever reach that point.

Here I am making two requests (more or less, two types of)

```
$('#keyInput_user_FORM').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var APIKeyInput_user = document.getElementsByName("APIKeyInput_user")[0].value;

        var accountAPI = baseAPI + versionAPI[1] + "/" + endpointAPI[0] + "?" + bearerAPI[0] + "=" + APIKeyInput_user;
        $.getJSON( encodeURI(accountAPI), {
            tagmode: "any",
            format: "json"
        }).done(function( data ) {
            $.each( data.guilds, function( i, guilds ) {
                var guildDetailsAPI = baseAPI + versionAPI[0] + "/" + endpointAPI[1] + "?" + bearerAPI[1] + "=" + guilds;
                $.getJSON( encodeURI(guildDetailsAPI), {
                    tagmode: "any",
                    format: "json"
                }).done(function( data ) {
                    $(".guildIdentifiers_coll ul").append('&lt;li class="guildIdentifiers_indiv" id="'+data.guild_id+'"&gt;&lt;div id="gw2embelm-div"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;p&gt;' + data.guild_name + '&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/li&gt;');
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

These are the urls that it's calling. 
https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/account?access_token=EDCD27E4-3A1B-3C44-9C5B-99F062596A9BB1C9C824-AE01-4F6F-9EA9-CBAD2D721C9D

https://api.guildwars2.com/v1/guild_details.json?guild_name=Erasure%20of%20the%20mordant%20crescent

And finally here I am using the exact same call type but am refused (error at the top)

```
$.getJSON( encodeURI(bankAPI), {
            tagmode: "any",
            format: "json"
        }).done(function( data ) {
            $.each( data[0].inventory, function( i, inventory ) {
                $(".bankResult .bankResult_DIV").append('&lt;div class="bankInventory_item&gt;'+inventory+'&lt;/div&gt;"'); 
            });
        });
```

And this is the url thats being refused in aboves code.

https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/guild/927CDDD7-4E8D-E411-A8E7-AC162DAE5A05/stash?access_token=EDCD27E4-3A1B-3C44-9C5B-99F062596A9BB1C9C824-AE01-4F6F-9EA9-CBAD2D721C9D

The question. Why is it refused though being successful the first two times..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second url is missing the required 'guild_id'. Try using this instead.

https://api.guildwars2.com/v1/guild_details.json?guild_name=Erasure%20of%20the%20mordant%20crescent&guild_id=927CDDD7-4E8D-E411-A8E7-AC162DAE5A05

UPDATE
Here's the snippet I was using to test out your API calls. Maybe it will help you spot something I missed.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var logResults = function (url, label) {
  $.getJSON(encodeURI(url), {
    tagmode: "any",
    format: "json"
  }).done(function (data) {
    console.log('--------' + label + '--------');
    console.log(url);
    console.log(data);
  });
};

var accountAPI ="https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/account" +
        "?access_token=EDCD27E4-3A1B-3C44-9C5B-99F062596A9BB1C9C824-AE01-4F6F-9EA9-CBAD2D721C9D";

var secondUrl_notWorking = "https://api.guildwars2.com/v1/guild_details.json" +
                           "?guild_name=Erasure%20of%20the%20mordant%20crescent";

var secondUrl_working = "https://api.guildwars2.com/v1/guild_details.json" +
                        "?guild_id=927CDDD7-4E8D-E411-A8E7-AC162DAE5A05";

var bankAPI = 'https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/guild/927CDDD7-4E8D-E411-A8E7-AC162DAE5A05/stash' +
              '?access_token=EDCD27E4-3A1B-3C44-9C5B-99F062596A9BB1C9C824-AE01-4F6F-9EA9-CBAD2D721C9D';

logResults(accountAPI, 'accountAPI');
logResults(secondUrl_notWorking, 'secondUrl_notWorking');
logResults(secondUrl_working, 'secondUrl_working');
logResults(bankAPI, 'bankAPI');
  });
```

Comment: That one works just fine as you can either supply a guild_name or a guild_id, either works. If you supply both it will use the guild_id.

The problem is in the last,third, code and link, thats where I get my error. https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/guild/927CDDD7-4E8D-E411-A8E7-AC162DAE5A05/stash?access_token=EDCD27E4-3A1B-3C44-9C5B-99F062596A9BB1C9C824-AE01-4F6F-9EA9-CBAD2D721C9D

Comment: weird. I'm not getting the error with the third url. I only see it with the second.